# Recommended Blog Engine for ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blogs

I am building a website in ASP.NET MVC 4. I want a lot of control over this site. For this reason, I'm not using a full blown CMS. However, I would like to integrate a blog engine into my site.

What is the most recommended blog engine for an ASP.NET MVC site?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[oxite](http://oxite.codeplex.com/) its an mvc blog engine. There are lots of other blogs that use web forms, which wouldn't be that hard to implement